# React Query: order of refetch queries?

Tags: react-query

When React Query needs to invalidate multiple queries, in which order does it do that? Or is it random?
Does it dispatch multiple requests together, or one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one at a time (no batching), and I don't think there is any specific ordering that you should rely upon.